# Missing argument to -exec

Tags: command-line

This is the command I'm entering.

```
find /home/things/backups -mtime +0 -exec echo "{}" >> /home/things/logs/backup.log \; -exec echo "Hourly rotate successful: $(date). {} was deleted." >> /home/things/logs/backup.log; \;
```

and the output is below.

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'

;: command not found
```

It creates the file backup.log fine, but the file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
find /home/things/backups -mtime +0 -exec \
    sh -c 'echo "$0" >> /home/things/logs/backup.log; echo "Hourly rotate successful: $(date). $0 was deleted." >> /home/things/logs/backup.log;' {} \;
```

We start a new shell `sh` with a command `-c` and the parameter `{}` (the `find` result). In the command we use this parameter via `$0`.

Comment: alright, now if I wanted to delete the files instead of the first echo would I just replace the echo with rm?

Comment: Sorry, be fair, I corrected your script. For a new question ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's reposition the redirections a bit and add some line breaks to see what you're actually running:

```
 >> /home/things/logs/backup.log \
   >> /home/things/logs/backup.log \
   find /home/things/backups -mtime +0 -exec echo "{}" \; \
     -exec echo "Hourly rotate successful: $(date). {} was deleted.";
   \;
```

- You're redirecting `find`'s output, not that of the commands run by `-exec`. This would affect the commands run using `-exec` since they are child processes and inherit open file descriptors, so the effect would be what you needed even if the way you went about it was weird.
- Then the `;` at the end of the second `exec` wasn't escaped. The `find` command got terminated there without a `;` for `exec`, causing the error. `find` quit immediately because of this, so no output was produced.
- The `\;` at the end is then processed by the shell. Usually, it would be a statement delimiter, but since it is escaped, it tries to run it as a command. This fails, naturally.

Consider simplifying the command:

```
find /home/things/backups -mtime +0 -exec \
  bash -c 'printf "%s\nHourly rotate successful: $(date). %s was deleted.\n" "$0" "$0"' {} \; \
  >> /home/things/logs/backup.log
```